# Oracle forms error pointing to jacob.jar & frmwebutil.jar

Tags: weblogic, oracleforms, jacob

The oracle forms is not loading in the browser issuing the following errors in the java console

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://xxxx:9001/forms/java/jacob.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://xxx:9001/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar
network: Cache entry not found [url:xxx:9001/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://xxxx:9001/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar with proxy=DIRECT
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://xxxxx:9001/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar
```

Input the URL hence the form should show up .

Comment: Put the required files in those directories (or point whatever is trying to find those files at the correct directories). This is not a programming problem (it appears to be a software configuration problem) and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: The files are already in the required directory.